# How to fix the HTTP Response splitting vulnerability with ESAPI

Tags: java, servlets, security, httprequest, esapi

after a recent findbugs (FB) run it complains about a: *Security - HTTP Response splitting vulnerability* The following code triggers it:

```
String referrer = req.getParameter("referrer");
 if (referrer != null) {
  launchURL += "&referrer="+(referrer);
 }
resp.sendRedirect(launchURL);
```

Basically the 'referrer' http parameter contains an url, to which, when clicking on a back button in our application the browser returns to. It is appended to the url as a parameter. After a bit research i know that i need to sanitize the referrer url. After a bit more research i found the [esapi](http://code.google.com/p/owasp-esapi-java/) project which seem to offer this kind of functionality:

```
//1st canonicalize
import org.owasp.esapi.Encoder;
import org.owasp.esapi.Validator;
import org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder;
import org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator;
[...]
Encoder encoder = new DefaultEncoder(new ArrayList<String>());
String cReferrer = encoder.canonicalize(referrer);
```

**However I didn't figure out how to detect e.g. jscript code or other stuff which doesn't belong to a referrer url. So how can I achieve that with esapi?**

I tried:

```
Validator validator = new DefaultValidator(encoder);
validator.isValidInput("Redirect URL",referrer,"HTTPParameterValue",512,false);
```

however this doesn't work. What I need is a function which results in:

http://www.google.com **(ok)**

http://www.google.com/login?dest=http://google.com/%0D%0ALocation: javascript:%0D%0A%0D%0Aalert(document.cookie) **(not ok)**

Or is it enough to call the following statement?

```
encoder.encodeForHTMLAttribute(referrer);
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my final solution if anyone is interested. First I canonicalize and then URL decode the string. If a CR or LF exists (\n \r) I just cut of the rest of that potential 'attack' string starting with \n or \r.

```
String sanitize(String url) throws EncodingException{
    
    Encoder encoder = new DefaultEncoder(new ArrayList<String>());
    //first canonicalize
    String clean = encoder.canonicalize(url).trim();
    //then url decode 
    clean = encoder.decodeFromURL(clean);
    
    //detect and remove any existent \r\n == %0D%0A == CRLF to prevent HTTP Response Splitting
    int idxR = clean.indexOf('\r');
    int idxN = clean.indexOf('\n');
    
    if(idxN >= 0 || idxR>=0){
        if(idxN<idxR){
            //just cut off the part after the LF
            clean = clean.substring(0,idxN);
        }
        else{
            //just cut off the part after the CR
            clean = clean.substring(0,idxR);
        }
    }
    
    //re-encode again
    return encoder.encodeForURL(clean);
}
```

Theoretically i could have later verified the value against 'HTTPParameterValue' regex which is defined in the ESAPI.properties however it didn't like colon in the http:// and I didn't investigated further.

And one more remark after testing it: Most modern browser nowadays (Firefox > 3.6, Chrome, IE10 etc.) detect this kind of vulnerability and do not execute the code...

Comment: Computing `encodeForURL(decodeFromURL(url))` can potentially corrupt your URLs.

Comment: @maurizeio How so?

Comment: We need to investigate N attempts before clean text.
Like this... `while(clean.contains(System.lineSeparator()))`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest white-listing approach wherein you check the `referrer` string only for permissible characters. Regex would be a good option.

**EDIT:**

The class `org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultEncoder` being used by you is not really encoding anything. Look at the source code of the method `encodeForHTMLAttribute(referrer)` [here at grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.owasp.esapi/esapi/2.0_rc10/org/owasp/esapi/reference/DefaultEncoder.java#DefaultEncoder.encodeForHTMLAttribute%28java.lang.String%29). A typical URL encoding (encoding  carriage return and line feed) [too wont help](http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/OT-Protecting-against-HTTP-response-splitting-td2174559.html).

So the way forward would be device some validation logic which checks for valid set of characters. Here is [another insightful article](http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5WP0E2KFGK.html).

Comment: Yeah but that's why i wanted to use esapi which (at least i though so) does that for me...

Answer (score 1):

I think you have the right idea, but are using an inappropriate encoder. The Referer [sic] header value is really a URL, not an HTML attribute, so you really want to use:

`encoder.encodeForURL(referrer);`

-kevin

Comment: Yeah you are right - encodeForURL is the correct method to use

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer will not work if in case there is "\n\r" in the string. 
Example: 
If I have string: `"This is str\n\rstr"`, it returns `"This is str\nstr"`

Rectified version of above accepted answer is:

```
 String sanitizeCarriageReturns(String value) {
        int idxR = value.indexOf('\r');
        int idxN = value.indexOf('\n');

        if (idxN >= 0 || idxR >= 0) {
            if ((idxN > idxR && idxR<0) || (idxR > idxN && idxR>=0)) {
                    value = value.substring(0, idxN);
                } else if (idxN < idxR){
                    value = value.substring(0, idxR);
                } 

        }
        return value;
    }
```